# Перенос строки внутри <summary>

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как можно перенести строку внутри `<summary></summary>` ?

На данный момент использую `<para></para>`, но новая строка начинается через ещё одну пустую.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`</br>`, вообще ничего не делает.

Так вот есть что то, что может перенести просто на следующую строку ?

Comment: вы, по идее, должны использовать [рекомендованные теги](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments) и `para` как раз существует как параграф. Но если уж хотите использовать `br` тег, до [делайте это правильно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DtS7.png), хотя я бы рекомендовал использовать тот тег, который существует в документации (`para`), а не `br`, который непонятно как вообще работает и не ясно будет ли дальше также работать.

Comment: @tym32167 Понял вас - спасибо - буду использовать что рекомендуется!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Visual Studio 2019 тег `<br/>` работает как внутри тега [para](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/codedoc#para), так и без него:

[image: Тег br без тега para]

[image: Тег br внутри тега para]

Также в Visual Studio 2019 появилась нормальная поддержка атрибута `href` в тегах [see](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/codedoc#see) и [seealso](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/codedoc#seealso)
*(ранее просто выводился адрес ссылки вместо содержимого тега)*

[image: Атрибут href в теге see]

Для форматирования текста можно воспользоваться тегами `<b></b>` и `<i></i>`.
*Для использования пробела между тегами, нужно вставлять его в теге, а не за его пределами, т.к. в этом случае он просто не будет отображаться*

[image: Теги форматирования текста b и i в XML комментариях Visual Studio]

Но как уже заметил [tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179763) следует избегать не документированных тегов.

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Документирование кода с помощью XML-комментариев](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/codedoc)
- [Рекомендуемые теги для комментариев документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments)